# Java Regex to check for date and time

Tags: java, regex

I'm using Datetime-local in one of the fields for user to input date and time; to check if if has valid format; these should be acceptable:
'yyyy-mm-dd HH'
'yyyy-mm-dd HH:MM' (this is the desired one tho)
'yyyy-mm-dd HH:MM:SS'

I've been trying some variations so far, came up with this but it does not work unfortunately. Where is the mistake?

```
"\\d{4}-[01]\\d-[0-3]\\d\\s[0-2](\\d:[0-5]\\d:([0-5]\\d)?)?"
```

Comment: "\\d{4}-[01]\\d-[0-3]\\d\\s[0-2](\\d:[0-5]\\d:([0-5]\\d)?)?"

idk why the previous one got cut, this one frm the comment is the one i've tested.

Comment: Not exactly the answer, but why use a regex when you can use DateTimeFormats ?

Comment: Rather than manually checking for what is "acceptable," you could take the approach of letting a Date API try to parse the input string, and then reacting appropriately to an exception should it occur.

Comment: @ŁukaszStasiak Don't add comments to correct your question -- edit the question.

Comment: This Q&A is pertinent: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29751244/how-to-validate-date-against-multiple-patterns-format-in-java   Particularly the actual question he is asking.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why you don't use `SimpleDateFormat` instead of regex :

```
try{
    SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:SS");
    format.parse("55555");
    System.out.println("Correct date");
}catch(ParseException e){
    System.out.println("Incorrect date");
}
```

---

If you want to use multiple you can use an Array which store your formats, for example :

```
String[] patterns = {"yyyy-MM-dd HH", "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm", ...};//<<---your formats

for (String pattern : patterns) {
    try {
        new SimpleDateFormat(pattern).parse("your date");
        System.out.println("Correct date");
        break;//if your date is correct break your look
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        System.out.println("Incorrect date");
    }
}
```

---

### Java 8 or Java 9

But I prefers to use the [java.time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) from Java 8 or Java 9, so you can solve your problem like this :

```
String[] patterns = {"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm", "yyyy-MM-dd HH"};
String date = "2018-02-02 11:50";
boolean check = Arrays.asList(patterns).stream()
        .anyMatch(pattern -> {
            try {
                LocalDateTime.parse(date, DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(pattern));
                System.out.println("Correct");
                return true;
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println("Not Correct");
                return false;
            }
        });
```

Comment: Would it allow optional minutes and seconds?

Comment: @AmberBeriwal the OP can use multiple format instead one, this is just an example :)

Comment: yes..multiple formats would be a possible solution.

Comment: That's good..but did you just copied that from Stephen's Comment :P

Comment: no, i don't from Stephen's comment @AmberBeriwal >:<

Comment: can you show me your code please @ŁukaszStasiak ? and your date that you tried to check?

Comment: FYI, the troublesome old date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`java.util.Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), and `java.text.SimpleDateFormat` are now [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system), supplanted by the [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes built into Java 8 & Java 9. See [*Tutorial* by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html).

Comment: Thank you @BasilBourque I was not have any idea about java.time when i write this answer, I edit now ;)

Answer (score 6):

Although, as suggested in comments, `SimpleDateFormat.parse()` is a good, perfect and abstract solution, but if you still wanna try regular expressions, this should work:

```
\d{4}-[01]\d-[0-3]\d\s[0-2]\d((:[0-5]\d)?){2}
```

**Problem with your regular expression:**

- You are making `H` (second digit in hour) as optional.
- You are also making colon(`:`) as mandatory after `MM` which should be optional.
- This regex would not check the combination of months, years and hours. Mine with also not check.

Comment: still getting mistake even tho your regex is valid (checked in http://www.regexplanet.com/advanced/java/index.html) ... guess it's for another time tho. thanks for answering :)

Comment: @ŁukaszStasiak Glad I could be of help.